# Transparent Div

Tags: css, html, stylesheet

I have 2 divs stacked. Means 1 div is on another div.

Both div has transparent background color.

So, when div is shown, both div in lower also shows because upper div is transparent.

If there is any way to make upper or lower div such that only upper div's shows with transparent background.

Means if there is image element stacked below lower div, image should be shown because uppder div is transparent but not color shows should be sum of both div's transparent colors.

So, current 
[image]

Comment: Can someone help describing what OP wants. I more or less understood until "but not color shows should be sum of both div's transperant colors."

Comment: There's no code at all.

Answer (score 0):

Sadly in CSS there is no way to make a daughter element not inherit the transparency setting of the parent element. The best thing to do is to make div with the transparency on, then make a similar div of the same dimensions and what not and then position it, absolutely, over the transparent div. Then anything you want to remain non-transparent you can simply place in the second div.

If this doesn't make sense, reply and I'll try to make it clearer.

Mike.